# How do I store a text's original formatting pre-running VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some code that toggles a selected text's font color through pre-determined colors (black > red > green > black, etc.). What I'd really like to do, though, is make it more dynamic for whatever formatting my presentation is already in.

For instance, if I run the macro on a portion of a slide's title that's formatted to be blue, I don't have a good way of getting back to the original blue. I've thought about "copying" the formatting to some sort of variable, but I'm not sure how I'd accurately clear the variable or store it for later.

What seems more likely is to build in some sort of "context" search. If I can look to the left and right of the selected text, there may be some input into what color text should be (as it very rarely needs to differ within a text block). But this is quickly getting outside my know-how.

See code below for the current setup.

```
Sub TextColorSwap()

On Error Resume Next

With ActiveWindow.Selection
    If .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
        .TextRange.Font.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf .TextRange.Font.Color = vbRed Then
        .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 153, 0)
    Else
        .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Any thoughts from the pros?

-R

Answer (score 0):

How about somethign like this to get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Public bFirstColour As Boolean

Sub TextColorSwap()

  ' This will mask all errors, and if you don't have your own error handler,
  ' is bad practice as you'll never know if something's gone wrong.
  On Error Resume Next

  Dim lColour As Long
  Dim lCursor As Long

  With ActiveWindow.Selection

    If .Type = ppSelectionText Then
      ' Get the start position of the selected text
      lCursor = .TextRange.Start
      ' If there are characters to the left of the selected text, save the colour and set a flag
      If lCursor > 1 And Not bFirstColour Then
        lColour = .TextRange.Characters(1).Font.Color
        bFirstColour = True
      End If
      ' Toggle the colour
      With .TextRange.Font
        If .Color = lColour Then
          .Color = vbRed
        ElseIf .Color = vbRed Then
          .Color = RGB(0, 153, 0)
        Else
          ' Reset the colour to the colour fond to the left of the text
          .Color = lColour
          bFirstColour = False
        End If
      End With
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```